# vue-router: navigate to nested state/route by name and params

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

How can I navigate to a child state using `$router.push`?

My routes:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/customers", name: 'Customers',
    components: {content: CustomersMain},
    props: {header: true, content: false},
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: CustomerDetailsEmpty
      },
      {
        path: ':id',
        name: 'CustomerDetails',
        component: CustomerDetails
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

How can I navigate to `CustomerDetails` with an `id` param set using 
`$router.push`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
this.$router.push({ name: `CustomerDetails`, params: {id} });
```

Comment: is there any reason to use backtick: ` ` other than inverted comma:  ' ' ? inverted comma also works.